# How do I use Google Web Fonts for Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, google-fonts

A number of 2010 blog posts from Google seems to imply this is possible, but I can't seem to move fonts from Web Fonts to Google Documents. Is it even doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. They [announced](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-fontastic-google-docs.html) that they are using Google Fonts API internally and added few fonts from that list. You're not able to add any font you like.

Comment: Disappointing, but at least that clears up my confusion.

Comment: @Alex I think it's Font API and not FontS API since Google is using the singular form as from here: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-google-font-api-google-font.html

Comment: The link in that article leads to [here](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/), where is _fonts_.

Comment: @Alex True.. and it's more natural, so Fonts it is :)